# Android Adding Account with AccountManager

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

Hey guys im trying to add an account with androids accountManager, I keep getting this stack trace below.

Guys I cant post all of my code cause I break the limit that Stack Overflow allows me to enter. so ill only post snippets of code you request cause there is WAY more code for this. Sorry for the messy code im just messing around with it till I can get it to work then ill clean it up.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.rapid.rapid, PID: 6168
java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10335 cannot explicitly add accounts of type: com.example.rapid.rapid
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
    at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.addAccountExplicitly(IAccountManager.java:890)
    at android.accounts.AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(AccountManager.java:716)
    at com.example.rapid.rapid.LoginActivity$1$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:174)
    at com.example.rapid.rapid.LoginActivity$1$1.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:140)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    public final static String ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.example.rapid.rapid";
    public final static String ARG_AUTH_TYPE = "AUTH_TYPE";
    public final static String ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME = "com.example.rapid.rapid";
    public final static String ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT = "IS_ADDING_ACCOUNT";
    public static final String KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE = "ERR_MSG";
    public final static String PARAM_USER_PASS = "USER_PASS";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;
    private AccountManager mAccountManager;
    public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.example.rapid.rapid";
    private static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.rapid.rapid";
    private static final String PREF_SETUP_COMPLETE = "setup_complete";
    private static final long SYNC_FREQUENCY = 60 * 60;  // 1 hour (in seconds)
    private String mAuthTokenType;
    private boolean mInvalidate;
    private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

    @InjectView(R.id.loginEmailWrapper)
    TextInputLayout _loginEmailWrapper;
    @InjectView(R.id.loginPasswordWrapper)
    TextInputLayout _loginPasswordWrapper;
    @InjectView(R.id.loginEmailInput)
    EditText _loginEmailInput;
    @InjectView(R.id.loginPasswordInput)
    EditText _loginPasswordInput;
    @InjectView(R.id.loginPasswordVisibility)
    ImageView _loginPasswordVisibility;
    @InjectView(R.id.btn_login)
    Button _loginButton;
    @InjectView(R.id.link_signup)
    TextView _signupLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*Uncomment this to make this screen of the app fullscreen.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

        boolean setupComplete = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(PREF_SETUP_COMPLETE, false);

        String accountName = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        mAuthTokenType = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_AUTH_TYPE);
        if (mAuthTokenType == null)
            mAuthTokenType = AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS;

        if (accountName != null) {
            _loginEmailInput.setText(accountName);
        }

        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Begin Login process...");
                showAccountPicker(mAuthTokenType, false);

                if (!validate()) {
                    onLoginFailed();
                    return;
                }

                final String email = _loginEmailInput.getText().toString();
                final String password = _loginPasswordInput.getText().toString();

                final String accountType = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

                _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
                        R.style.Theme_IAPTheme);
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
                progressDialog.show();



                // Response received from the server
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        String authtoken = null;
                        boolean newAccount = false;
                        try {
                            Log.i("tagconvertstr", "[" + response + "]");
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                String trainer_name = jsonResponse.getString("trainer_name");
                                authtoken = jsonResponse.getString("token");
                                //String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");

                                //Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserHomeActivity.class);
                                //intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                //intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                //LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                //Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserHomeActivity.class);
                                //LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                //startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                                String accountName = AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME;
                                String accountPassword = password;
                                //final Account account = new Account(email, "com.example.rapid.rapid");

                                if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true)) {
                                    Log.d("rapid", TAG + "> finishLogin > addAccountExplicitly");
                                    authtoken = AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN;
                                    String authtokenType = mAuthTokenType;

                                    Account account = rapidAuthenticatorService.GetAccount(ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                                    AccountManager accountManager =
                                            (AccountManager) getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
                                    if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null)) {
                                        // Inform the system that this account supports sync
                                        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, 1);
                                        // Inform the system that this account is eligible for auto sync when the network is up
                                        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, true);
                                        // Recommend a schedule for automatic synchronization. The system may modify this based
                                        // on other scheduled syncs and network utilization.
                                        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(
                                                account, CONTENT_AUTHORITY, new Bundle(),SYNC_FREQUENCY);
                                        newAccount = true;
                                    }

                                    if (newAccount) {
                                        TriggerRefresh();
                                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit()
                                                .putBoolean(PREF_SETUP_COMPLETE, true).commit();

                                    }

                                    Log.d("rapid", TAG + "> ALL SETUP!");
                                    // Creating the account on the device and setting the auth token we got
                                    // (Not setting the auth token will cause another call to the server to authenticate the user)
                                    //mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null);
                                    //mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, authtokenType, authtoken);
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("rapid", TAG + "> finishLogin > setPassword");
                                    //mAccountManager.setPassword(account, accountPassword);
                                    Log.d("rapid", TAG + "> done setting account password");
                                }

                                //setAccountAuthenticatorResult(intent.getExtras());
                                //setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserHomeActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("trainer_name", trainer_name);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                onLoginFailed();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(email, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);


            }
        });

        _loginPasswordInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //_registerPasswordVisibility.setVisibility(s.length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //_registerPasswordVisibility.setVisibility(s.length() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                //_trainerNameWrapper.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
            }
        });
        _loginPasswordVisibility.setOnTouchListener(mPasswordVisibleTouchListener);

        _signupLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the Signup activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void TriggerRefresh() {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        // Disable sync backoff and ignore sync preferences. In other words...perform sync NOW!
        b.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        b.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(
                rapidAuthenticatorService.GetAccount(ACCOUNT_TYPE), // Sync account
                CONTENT_AUTHORITY,                 // Content authority
                b);                                             // Extras
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener mPasswordVisibleTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final boolean isOutsideView = event.getX() < 0 ||
                    event.getX() > v.getWidth() ||
                    event.getY() < 0 ||
                    event.getY() > v.getHeight();

            // change input type will reset cursor position, so we want to save it
            final int cursor = _loginPasswordInput.getSelectionStart();

            if (isOutsideView || MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction())
                _loginPasswordInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            else
                _loginPasswordInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);

            _loginPasswordInput.setSelection(cursor);
            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Show all the accounts registered on the account manager. Request an auth token upon user select.
     *
     * @param authTokenType
     */
    private void showAccountPicker(final String authTokenType, final boolean invalidate) {
        mInvalidate = invalidate;
        final Account availableAccounts[] = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        if (availableAccounts.length == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No accounts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            String name[] = new String[availableAccounts.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < availableAccounts.length; i++) {
                name[i] = availableAccounts[i].name;
            }

            // Account picker
            mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Pick Account").setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (invalidate)
                        invalidateAuthToken(availableAccounts[which], authTokenType);
                    else
                        getExistingAccountAuthToken(availableAccounts[which], authTokenType);
                }
            }).create();
            mAlertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the auth token for an existing account on the AccountManager
     *
     * @param account
     * @param authTokenType
     */
    private void getExistingAccountAuthToken(Account account, String authTokenType) {
        final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(account, authTokenType, null, this, null, null);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Bundle bnd = future.getResult();

                    final String authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    showMessage((authtoken != null) ? "SUCCESS!\ntoken: " + authtoken : "FAIL");
                    Log.d("udinic", "GetToken Bundle is " + bnd);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showMessage(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * Invalidates the auth token for the account
     *
     * @param account
     * @param authTokenType
     */
    private void invalidateAuthToken(final Account account, String authTokenType) {
        final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(account, authTokenType, null, this, null, null);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Bundle bnd = future.getResult();

                    final String authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    mAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken(account.type, authtoken);
                    showMessage(account.name + " invalidated");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    showMessage(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * Get an auth token for the account.
     * If not exist - add it and then return its auth token.
     * If one exist - return its auth token.
     * If more than one exists - show a picker and return the select account's auth token.
     *
     * @param accountType
     * @param authTokenType
     */
    private void getTokenForAccountCreateIfNeeded(String accountType, String authTokenType) {
        final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures(accountType, authTokenType, null, this, null, null,
                new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                    @Override
                    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                        Bundle bnd = null;
                        try {
                            bnd = future.getResult();
                            final String authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                            showMessage(((authtoken != null) ? "SUCCESS!\ntoken: " + authtoken : "FAIL"));
                            Log.d("udinic", "GetTokenForAccount Bundle is " + bnd);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            showMessage(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                , null);
    }

    private void showMessage(final String msg) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(msg))
            return;

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

rapidAuthenticator.java

```
public class rapidAuthenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {

    private String TAG = "rapidAuthenticator";
    private final Context mContext;

    public rapidAuthenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // I hate you! Google - set mContext as protected!
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        Log.d("rapid", TAG + "> addAccount");

        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);
        intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);

        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {

        Log.d("udinic", TAG + "> getAuthToken");

        // If the caller requested an authToken type we don't support, then
        // return an error
        if (!authTokenType.equals(AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY) && !authTokenType.equals(AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS)) {
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, "invalid authTokenType");
            return result;
        }

        // Extract the username and password from the Account Manager, and ask
        // the server for an appropriate AuthToken.
        final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(mContext);

        String authToken = am.peekAuthToken(account, authTokenType);

        Log.d("udinic", TAG + "> peekAuthToken returned - " + authToken);

        // Lets give another try to authenticate the user
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            final String password = am.getPassword(account);
            if (password != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("udinic", TAG + "> re-authenticating with the existing password");
                    authToken = sServerAuthenticate.userSignIn(account.name, password, authTokenType);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        // If we get an authToken - we return it
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            final Bundle result = new Bundle();
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
            result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, authToken);
            return result;
        }

        // If we get here, then we couldn't access the user's password - so we
        // need to re-prompt them for their credentials. We do that by creating
        // an intent to display our AuthenticatorActivity.
        final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
        intent.putExtra(LoginActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
        return bundle;
    }


    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
        if (AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS.equals(authTokenType))
            return AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS_LABEL;
        else if (AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY.equals(authTokenType))
            return AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_READ_ONLY_LABEL;
        else
            return authTokenType + " (Label)";
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
        final Bundle result = new Bundle();
        result.putBoolean(KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, false);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rapid.rapid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />

    <application>
        <service android:name="com.example.rapid.rapid.rapidAuthenticatorService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Authenticator.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:accountType="com.example.rapid.rapid"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:smallIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="rapid"
        android:accountPreferences="@xml/prefs"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As exception says, **caller uid** is different than the **authenticator's uid**. To add a account explicitly, **caller** and **authenticator's uid** should be same.

This should be same as your **app id**, i.e **package name**.

```
android:accountType="com.example.rapid.rapid"
```

[Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addAccountExplicitly(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))

> This method requires the caller to have a signature match with the
>   authenticator that owns the specified account.

Comment: So I want to extend this by pointing out what it was SPECIFICALLY for me, and @Daud is right! my package name always was "com.example.rapid.rapid" and notice I have the 2 rapid.rapid in a row, I have a weird folder structure setup so after I changed the account type to android:accountType="com.example.rapid" it worked, I dont know why this is cause the package name is with the two rapid's but for whatever reason removing one of them from the accountType fixed it. So hopefully this helps out other people, and thanks Daud! Im accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but got it fixed after I restarted the device. It might help to try it out.